# How to print a JSON API to data frames in Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've seen a bunch of fixes for similar issues, but I can't seem to figure out what's different for this particular API.

I'm new to this, but trying to play with a private link for work to see if I can expediate a manual process I'm dealing with.

I've tried several scripts with a public API that work -- I thought it was a permissions error, but I actually am able to print the API feed to TERMINAL with this script, which gives me hope:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import certifi
# urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
       cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
       ca_certs=certifi.where())


# url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'
url = 'realurl'
req = rq.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')


print(soup)
```

If I'm able to print to terminal, I should be able to print to a Google Sheet (or at least a CSV, I would think)... my issue is creating the DataFrames; I've tried a bunch of different methods, but I keep seeing various errors - this one being "Object of type method is not JSON serializable"

All I want to do is append the data to the G Sheet I set up with Gspread:

```
import gspread
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import json
import urllib3
from urllib3 import request
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('sheetkey')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}


# url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'
url = 'realurl'
req = rq.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')


df1 = pd.DataFrame(soup)

df = df1.to_json

# pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
# pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

AddData = [df]
worksheet.append_row(AddData)
```

All the fixes I see on this point me to adding _toCSV or _toDict on my object... but I've tried adding it everywhere.

I'm also confused why it's saying I need in JSON format, when the original API is in JSON format.

Am I missing something here?  I basically just want to take the data set from my fist code and create DataFrames so I can print to a G Sheet.  Any advice would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Update:

I am now printing one category title from the feed to the sheet with this:

```
import gspread
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import json
import urllib3
from urllib3 import request
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('key')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}


# url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'


url = 'realurl'
req = rq.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')


# df1 = pd.DataFrame(soup)
dfs = json.loads(str(soup))

for df in dfs:
    print(df)

# pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
# pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

AddData = [df]
worksheet.append_row(AddData)
```

FURTHER UPDATE:

To be clear, the issue comes from pushing the data to the Google Sheet.  The answer from @Furas works to print the data, but not when paired with Gspread like below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import gspread


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1-1aiGMn2yUWRlh_jnIebcMNs-6phzUNxkktAFH7uY9o')
worksheet = sh.sheet1



url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'

response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

data = response.json()
# print(data)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# print(df)


AddData = [df]
worksheet.append_row(AddData)
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\JSON-Fetch\FinalTry.py", line 26, in <module>
    worksheet.append_row(AddData)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\worksheet.py", line 1289, in append_row
    return self.append_rows(
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\worksheet.py", line 1338, in append_rows
    return self.spreadsheet.values_append(range_label, params, body)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\spreadsheet.py", line 149, in values_append
    r = self.client.request("post", url, params=params, json=body)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 73, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 549, in request
    response = super(AuthorizedSession, self).request(
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 319, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 469, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: not sure if it helps or hurt, but I think I need to json.loads to parse the json string into a dict... trying to figure that part out but nothing yet

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe first use `print(req.text)` to see what you really get from url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you use `BeautifulSoup` for this.
It is for `HTML` or `XML` but not for `JSON` or `CSV`.

---

If page sends `JSON` data then you need only

```
data = req.json()
```

to get it as python dictionary.

And if you want to convert to `DataFrame` then

```
df = pd.json_normalize(req.json())
```

---

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'

response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

data = response.json()
print(data)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

---

And if page sends `CSV` then you can even use directly `pandas`

```
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

eventually you can use `requests` with `io.StringIO` to create file-like object in memory

```
import io

response = requests.get(url, ...)

file_like_object = io.StringIO(response.text)

df = pd.read_csv(file_like_object)
```

But all depends on real url which you didn't show in question.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to add it to Google Sheet then you don't need `DataFrame` but python's dictionary

```
data = response.json()

worksheet.append_row([data])
```

If JSON may have list with many items then you may need `for`-loop to put data in separated rows

```
data = response.json()

for item in data:
    worksheet.append_row([item])
```

---

If you really have to use `pandas` then read documentation [Using gspread with pandas](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#using-gspread-with-pandas)

It may need something like this

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    worksheet.append_row(row.values.tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - it prints correctly but the issue still comes from pushing to sheet (even though the connection works there).  I would love to just get the data from the link in the updated script working and then I can recreate for the private URL I'm working with @furas

Comment: if you want to add to Sheet then you should work with python's dictionary, not with DataFrame. OR even you may need to use `for`-loop to put every element in separated row.

Comment: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/